# Unable to run Camera Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I tried to run the demo code provided in the capture class in the [documentation](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/index.html) to click a photo but it gives me the following error:-

```
java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 64
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.loadTheme(Resources.java:1270)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFileImpl(Resources.java:303)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFile(Resources.java:269)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:189)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:768)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:688)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$4.run(JavaSEPort.java:1556)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1152)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:969)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Layout doesn't support adding with arguments: com.codename1.ui.layouts.FlowLayout
    at com.codename1.ui.layouts.Layout.addLayoutComponent(Layout.java:64)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.addComponent(Container.java:557)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.addComponent(Form.java:1214)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.add(Container.java:198)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:165)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:123)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1152)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:969)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

The UTFDataFormatException is always there in a new hello world program too and hasn't affected the running of any code I've written until now. But the IllegalStateException crashes the app in the simulator. It also doesn't point to the line which raises this exception in my code.

Comment: Kindly provide the code you used for the camera capturing.

Comment: @Diamond I was able to run the code after playing with it for a bit. I have posted the code down if you want to have a look and maybe help me understand why the commented out code(sample code) gave the above error. Thanks

Comment: Check the Java installations on your machine, make sure that JDK 8 is the first one in the path and the one defined in JAVA_HOME. Check the resource file itself, see if it's 0 sized if it's not does it open in the designer from command line https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-track-designer-guibuilder-issues.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few playing around with the code, I was able to launch the camera successfully. The following is the running code for the benefits of others who may experience a similar problem:-

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;


import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.FontImage;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Graphics;
import com.codename1.ui.Image;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.Style;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.capture.Capture;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.ui.Toolbar;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * This file was generated by <a href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the purpose 
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */
public class Camera {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
        // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
//        Form hi = new Form("Rounder", new BorderLayout());
//        Label picture = new Label("", "Container");
//        hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, picture);
//        hi.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0xff0000);
//        hi.getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
//        Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand");
//        Image camera = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_CAMERA, s);
//        hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar("", camera, (ev) -> {
//            try {
//                int width = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();
//                Image capturedImage = Image.createImage(Capture.capturePhoto(width, -1));
//                Image roundMask = Image.createImage(width, capturedImage.getHeight(), 0xff000000);
//                Graphics gr = roundMask.getGraphics();
//                gr.setColor(0xffffff);
//                gr.fillArc(0, 0, width, width, 0, 360);
//                Object mask = roundMask.createMask();
//                capturedImage = capturedImage.applyMask(mask);
//                picture.setIcon(capturedImage);
//                hi.revalidate();
//            } catch(IOException err) {
//                Log.e(err);
//            }
//        });
        Form hi = new Form("Camera", new BorderLayout());
        Label picture = new Label("", "Container");
        hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,picture);
        Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand");
        Image camera = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_CAMERA, s);
        hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar("", camera, ev -> {
            try {
                Image image = Image.createImage(Capture.capturePhoto());
                picture.setIcon(image);
                hi.revalidate();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e(e);
            }
        });
        hi.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be something seriously wrong with your installation of Codename One. That exception should never happen and indicates that something major is broken.

Comment: So what do you suggest I do to make this go away?

Comment: I suggest going over the process of installing Codename One again. Specifically pay attention to the VM used in the install. Is it an Oracle JDK 1.8 or something else? Any other detail that might make things problematic?

Comment: I uninstalled the CodeName One plugin fromo the Eclipse Market and re-installed it. Gives the same error again. And yes, my JDK has been downloaded from the oracle site and is JDK 8 (or 1.8). Anything else I should check to make this go away?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I'm having the same problem (Oracle Java 8, new Eclipse 4.7.0, fresh plugin install), also at byte 64, identical stack trace except for showing lines numbers in `at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:656)` and `at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)`. You're providing you own much smaller `DataInputStream` in `CLDC11.jar`, but it looks like the one from the system gets used. No idea if OpenJdk/Oracle differ in this point, but your provided version is supposed to be used, isn't it? There's OpenJdk on my Linux as well, but Oracle is the default.

Comment: This could be related to this issue which was supposed to be fixed https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2082 try launching eclipse from the working directory